# Access Rules created by WSAT are not enforced

Tags: asp.net-membership

I'm trying to implement roles in my site.

There are several projects in the solution, one of which is a web application.

In that web application, I'm trying to use WSAT to create three roles.  There are many folders for the application.  I've used WSAT to define role based access rules for each folder.

However, when I debug and navigate to those pages, they do not redirect to a login and show me the protected page.

There are web.config files in each folder.

Why would the system not enforce these rules?

My web.config file has:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlProvider" />
```

I've tested the connections in WSAT and they work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I fixed the problem.

A previous developer had cleared all the HTTP modules.  Since all the modules were disabled, the authentication module wasn't part of the asp.net pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<roleManager enabled="true"/>
```

Also, please edit your question to provide the web.config from one of your subdirectories.